# Where are the test for Scala collections?

Tags: scala, testing, scala-collections

I am looking for tests which can be used for custom collections. Ideally these are behaviour tests.
For example implementing a new `Map` I would like to test if it follows all required `Map`-rules and
methods like `map`, `filter`, `view`, etc.

What is Scala using to test its own collections?

Comment: I would say that the official Github repo is a good place to start: https://github.com/scala/scala

Comment: Thanks, this was one of the first places I searched, but I could not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question that has been asked before on SO.

There are some collections tests under `test/files/scalacheck` and others under `test/files/run/*coll*` in the source repository.

There is no conformance test or TCK per se for custom collections.  Integration with collections usually involves a specific implementation requirement.

For example, the ScalaDoc for `immutable.MapLike` tells you to implement `get`, `iterator` and `+` and `-`.  In theory, if you test the template methods, you can rely on everything you get for free from the library.

But the doc adds:

> It is also good idea to override methods foreach and size for
>   efficiency.

So if you care about that, you'll be adding performance tests too.  The standard library doesn't include automated performance testing.

Comment: Thanks, that will then be my starting point. However I don't feel comfortable. I don't trust people (especially me) to implement things correct without a test that "proofs" it is.